# Problem witch Hibernate save on many to many

Tags: java, hibernate

i have a problem with a hibernate save operation.

When i try to save an object

```
Session session = FACTORY.getCurrentSession();
Transaction trans=session.beginTransaction();
session.save(objeto);
trans.commit();
```

the log show the next exception

> 21:59:39,994 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-5) org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions. Collection : [es.ddmain.entidades.Juego.juegosEnStore#1]: javax.el.ELException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions. Collection : [es.ddmain.entidades.Juego.juegosEnStore#1]
> at org.glassfish.javax.el@3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1//com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:187)
> at org.glassfish.javax.el@3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1//com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
> at org.glassfish.javax.el@3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1//com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
> at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:126)
> at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:72)
> at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:490)
> at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:211)
> at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:847)
> at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1395)
> at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:58)
> at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
> at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:177)
> at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:707)
> at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
> at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
> at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
> at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
> at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
> at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
> at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
> at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
> at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
> at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
> at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
> at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
> at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
> at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
> at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
> at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
> at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions. Collection : [es.ddmain.entidades.Juego.juegosEnStore#1]
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.setCurrentSession(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:699)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.event.internal.WrapVisitor.processCollection(WrapVisitor.java:71)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:104)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.event.internal.WrapVisitor.processValue(WrapVisitor.java:131)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(AbstractVisitor.java:59)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.visitCollectionsBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:366)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:272)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:179)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:75)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:677)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:670)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:665)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:351)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//com.sun.proxy.$Proxy101.save(Unknown Source)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//es.ddmain.dao.impl.JuegoDAOImpl.guardar(JuegoDAOImpl.java:97)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//es.ddmain.dao.impl.JuegoDAOImpl.guardar(JuegoDAOImpl.java:25)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//es.ddmain.servicios.impl.ServicioJuegoImpl.guardar(ServicioJuegoImpl.java:36)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//es.ddmain.servicios.impl.FachadaImpl.guardar(FachadaImpl.java:46)
> at deployment.videogamesPersonalManager-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war//es.ddmain.beans.ListadoDeseadosBean.modificar(ListadoDeseadosBean.java:159)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at org.glassfish.javax.el@3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1//com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)

My entities are

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "whislist")
public class Juego implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4151736911313824434L;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="idWhislist")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long idJuego;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nombre;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int posicion;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Integer nivel;
    
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Date fechaLanzamiento;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "juego")
    private Set<JuegoEnStore> juegosEnStore;
    
    // GETTERS && SETTERS

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "whislistinstore")
@IdClass(JuegoEnStoreId.class)
public class JuegoEnStore implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4141985115157735120L;
    
    
    // CAMPOS DE BBDD
    
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idWhislist", referencedColumnName = "idWhislist")
    private Juego juego;
    
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idStore", referencedColumnName = "idStore")
    private Store store;
    
    @Column(name="precioOriginal")
    private BigDecimal precioOriginal;
    
    @Column(name="precioActual")
    private BigDecimal precioActual;
    
    @Column(name="precioMinimo")
    private BigDecimal precioMinimo;
    
    @Column(name="dlcs", columnDefinition = "TINYINT")
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
    private boolean dlcs;
    
    @Column(name="precioDLCs")
    private BigDecimal precioDLCs;
    
    @Column(name="precioCompleto")
    private BigDecimal precioCompleto;
    
    @Column(name="drm", columnDefinition = "TINYINT")
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
    private boolean drm;
    
    @Column(name="nombreDRM")
    private String nombreDRM;
    
    @Column(name="comentarios")
    private String comentarios;
    
    @Column(name="earlyAccess", columnDefinition = "TINYINT")
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
    private boolean earlyAccess;
    
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idIdioma")
    private Idioma idioma;
    
    @Formula(value = "round((precioOriginal - precioMinimo) / precioOriginal * 100, 2)")
    private BigDecimal descuento;

    // SETTERS Y GETTERS
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "store")
public class Store implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3859365948690038372L;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="idStore")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long idStore;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nombre;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String logo;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "store")
    private Set<JuegoEnStore> juegosEnStore;
    
    // GETTERS Y SETTERS
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "idioma")
public class Idioma implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3005625482252394246L;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="idIdioma")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long idIdioma;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nombre;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String bandera;

    @Column(name="defecto", columnDefinition = "TINYINT", nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
    private boolean defecto;
    
    // SETTERS Y GETTERS
}
```

My DAO and superclasses and interfaces

```
public class JuegoDAOImpl implements JuegoDAO {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JuegoDAOImpl.class);
    
    @Override
    public void guardar(Juego objeto) {
        Session session = FACTORY.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction trans=session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(objeto);
        trans.commit();
    }
}

public interface JuegoDAO extends GenericDAO<Juego> {
    
    public List<Juego> obtenerJuegos(FiltroJuegos filtro);

}


public interface GenericDAO<T> {
    
    public final static StandardServiceRegistry SSR = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
    public final static Metadata META = new MetadataSources(SSR).getMetadataBuilder().build();
    public final static SessionFactory FACTORY = META.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
    
    public List<T> obtenerTodos();
    public void guardar(T objeto);
    public void actualizar(T objeto);
    public void borrar(T objeto);
    

}
```

Other classes involucrated

```
public class FachadaImpl implements Fachada {

    private ServicioJuego servicioJuego;
    
    @Override
    public void guardar(Juego objeto) {
        servicioJuego.guardar(objeto);
    }
}

public class ServicioJuegoImpl implements ServicioJuego {

    private JuegoDAO juegoDAO;
        
    @Override
    public void guardar(Juego objeto) {
        juegoDAO.guardar(objeto);
    }
}
```

And my hibernate configuration file is

```
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <property name="connection.datasource">java:/vpmDS</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        
        <mapping class="es.ddmain.entidades.Juego" />
        <mapping class="es.ddmain.entidades.Store" />
        <mapping class="es.ddmain.entidades.JuegoEnStore" />
        <mapping class="es.ddmain.entidades.Idioma" />

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Probably would be useful to see also what is happening in these other classes:
es.ddmain.servicios.impl.ServicioJuegoImpl.guardar(ServicioJuegoImpl.java:36)
es.ddmain.servicios.impl.FachadaImpl.guardar(FachadaImpl.java:46)

Comment: @cdr89 classes added to the question

Comment: Have you already tried to save all the "juegosEnStore" before the "juego" that contains them?

Comment: No, I thought it would autosave on save Juego. Do I have to store them separately?